# DateRangeSlider Bokeh Widget Error, Cannot convert string to timestampdate

Tags: python, date, timestamp, widget, bokeh

I am trying to implement the DateRangeSlider Widget into my bokeh project. I am using the widget to adjust the amount of stock date present over a range that I have accumulated in the csv file. Whenever I move the slider widget

[image]

it gives me an error. [image]

I am assuming that the datatypes used are incorrect. The issue lies in my update function.

How can I resolve this ?

```
from math import pi
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
from datetime import date
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, PrintfTickFormatter, CDSView,BooleanFilter
from bokeh.models.widgets import PreText, Select, DateRangeSlider, Button, DataTable, TableColumn, NumberFormatter
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show, reset_output
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file

DEFAULT_TICKERS = ['AAPL','GOOG','NFLX', 'TSLA']
ticker1 = Select(value='AAPL', options = DEFAULT_TICKERS)
range_slider1 = DateRangeSlider(start=date(2014,1,1) , end=date(2017,1,1), value=(date(2014,2,1),date(2016,3,1)), step=1)

def load_ticker(ticker):
    fname = ( '%s.csv' % ticker.lower())
    data = pd.read_csv( fname, header = None, parse_dates = ['Date'],
                  names =['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','AdjClose','Volume'])
    return data

def get_data(t1):
    data = load_ticker(t1)
    return data

def ticker1_change(attrname, old, new):
    update()

def range_slider_change(attrname, old, new):
    update()

def update(selected=None):
    t1 = ticker1.value
    sd = str(range_slider1.value[0])
    ed = str(range_slider1.value[1])
    start_date = sd
    end_date = ed

    datarange = get_data(t1)
    datarange['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datarange['Date'])

    mask = (datarange['Date'] > start_date) & (datarange['Date'] <= end_date)
    data = datarange.loc[mask]
    source.data = source.from_df(data)
    p.title.text = t1

data = get_data(ticker1.value)
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

p = figure(plot_width=900, plot_height=400, x_axis_type='datetime')
p.grid.grid_line_alpha = 0.3
p.line('Date', 'Close', source=source)


ticker1.on_change('value', ticker1_change)
range_slider1.on_change('value', range_slider_change)
update()

layout = column(ticker1,range_slider1, p)                                                              
curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "Stock"
```

Comment: A friendly aside: I spent ~5 minutes constructing a minimal example that was actually runnable from your incomplete example (you did not include or link to  necessary data or even provide a description of its format). I only did that because as a project maintainer and wanted to get to the bottom of the date/int issue described in the answer. Most people on SO will never have the time or inclination to do that. In the future, always include a ***complete, mininal example*** if you expect a response.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will be sure to do a more complete, and minimal example next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting `start_date` and `end_date` to strings:

```
sd = str(range_slider1.value[0])
ed = str(range_slider1.value[1])
start_date = sd
end_date = ed
```

And then using them where a `TimeStamp` is needed:

```
mask = (datarange['Date'] > start_date) & (datarange['Date'] <= end_date)
```

Which is exactly what the message "could not convert string to Timestamp" is telling you.

You need to convert the slider values to real `TimeStamp` objects. There is a slight wrinkle in that the slider value can be a `date` or and `int` (You might set it initially as a date, but at least as of Bokeh 0.13 it always comes back as a numeric timestamp, specifically, the number of millisecond since epoch. You have to handle both cases, here is one way:

```
if isinstance(range_slider1.value[0], (int, float)):
    # pandas expects nanoseconds since epoch
    start_date = pd.Timestamp(float(range_slider1.value[0])*1e6)
    end_date = pd.Timestamp(float(range_slider1.value[1])*1e6)
else:
    start_date = pd.Timestamp(range_slider1.value[0])
    end_date = pd.Timestamp(range_slider1.value[1])
```

This inconsistent behavior is considered a bug to be fixed in future releases. You can follow the issue here for more details: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8015